# How to replace an empty lists in polars (python)?

Tags: python, python-polars

Given a polars dataframe with empty lists in column values. How can I replace them with `pl.Null` or `None` in order to count them as missing values?

```
ine_items   contacts
list[null]  list[str]
[]  []
[]  []
[]  ["1081"]
[]  ["1313"]
[]  ["3657"]
```

```
df.with_columns(
   pl.when(pl.col(pl.List(pl.Null))
     .then(None)
     .otherwise(pl.col(pl.List()))
     .keep_name()
)
```

I can't seem to target the [] content with when() selector and I'm not sure, that `otherwise` block can keep the original value if the list is not empty (e.g. ['1246'])

Comment: All of the pl.List, pl.Float, pl.Int, and everything that starts with a capital letter are data types.  What you're looking for is `.arr.lengths()==0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Dean MacGregor mentioned, you can do this with .arr.lenghts()==0.

Here is the code for it:

```
import polars as pl

# example dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame({
        'contacts' : [[],[], ['1081'],['1313'],['3657']],
        'line_items' : [[],[],[],[],[]]
    }, schema=[('contacts',pl.List(pl.Utf8)), ('line_items',pl.List(pl.Utf8))]
)

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────────┬────────────┐
│ contacts  ┆ line_items │
│ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ list[str] ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════════╪════════════╡
│ []        ┆ []         │
│ []        ┆ []         │
│ ["1081"]  ┆ []         │
│ ["1313"]  ┆ []         │
│ ["3657"]  ┆ []         │
└───────────┴────────────┘

# transformation for 1 column

df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('contacts').arr.lengths() == 0)
        .then(None)
        .otherwise(pl.col('contacts')).keep_name(),
)

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────────┬────────────┐
│ contacts  ┆ line_items │
│ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ list[str] ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════════╪════════════╡
│ null      ┆ []         │
│ null      ┆ []         │
│ ["1081"]  ┆ []         │
│ ["1313"]  ┆ []         │
│ ["3657"]  ┆ []         │
└───────────┴────────────┘

# EDIT: added transformation for all columns of datatype List(Str)

df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col(column.name).arr.lengths() == 0)
            .then(None)
            .otherwise(pl.col(column.name))
            .keep_name() 
    for column in df if column.dtype == pl.List(pl.Utf8)
)

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────────┬────────────┐
│ contacts  ┆ line_items │
│ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ list[str] ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════════╪════════════╡
│ null      ┆ null       │
│ null      ┆ null       │
│ ["1081"]  ┆ null       │
│ ["1313"]  ┆ null       │
│ ["3657"]  ┆ null       │
└───────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks @luca, it works smoothly. Is there any way to make this column name agnostic? That's the reason, why I experimented with polars data types, to avoid specifying column names..

Comment: Hi @Valentine, I added an example for transforming based on the column type instead of the column name. So you can run it independently of column names

I also replaced the alias() with keep_name() for simplicity

Comment: I would use `df.schema` instead of accessing the whole df in your generator comprehension.  ie. `pl.when(pl.col(colname).arr.lengths() == 0).then(None).otherwise(pl.col(colname)).keep_name() for colname in [coltuple[0] for coltuple in df.schema.items() if coltuple[1] == pl.List(pl.Utf8)]`

Comment: Actually you can shorten it down to just `df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
        pl.col(colname).arr.lengths() > 0)
    .then(pl.col(colname))
        for colname in [coltuple[0] for coltuple in df.schema.items() if coltuple[1] == pl.List(pl.Utf8)]
)`

Comment: Also, it's good to put line breaks wherever long code would otherwise bring up the right/left scroll bar.  I did the line breaks edit but not the code edits.

Comment: Hi @DeanMacGregor thanks for the addition of df.schema. 

I imagine the advantage of it is about speed and that not the df is accessed with the list comprehension ?

Comment: @Luca when you loop through the df, it accesses the whole column.  For instance `for i in df: print(i)` gives each column as a series.  Maybe I'm mistaken and it, internally, does the same thing in either case, I'm not sure.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor: I just did 3 speed tests using a df with 100 millions:

Test 1- use arr.lengths() == 0 and loop through the df => 5.6 seconds +- 527 ms
Test 2 - use arr.lengths() > 0 and loop through df.schema => 5.6 seconds +- 561 ms
Test 3 - use arr.lengths() > 0 and loop through df => 5.6 seconds +- 526 ms

So it seems no increased time for looping the df. But maybe there is an overhead, just my small tests don't show it? I will change the code to > 0 as per your suggestion, it's shorter

Comment: yeah the >0 approach is just to make the code shorter, I didn't have any inkling that that would be more performant.  On the df vs df.schema, good to know.  Thanks for putting in the effort.